# How to make the spellchecker accept two languages at the same time in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, spell-check

I'm working in a bilingual environment and a lot of texts combine LangA and LangB (for example, documenting in LangB some procedure written in LangA or commenting a translation). Most of the time, a sentence might be in LangA and contains a few words in LangB or the opposite.

In Word  2007, is there a way **to not** make it mark a word as incorrect (little annoying red line) as long as it belongs to **any**  of the two dictionnaries, but still flag it if it's misspelt in both languages ?

Alternatively, could I create a "super" dictionnary from combining the two included in Word and force the application to use it ?

To answer some comments: It's usually not different block of text that are problematic. 
For whole sql statements or citations on several lines I've created a style that ignore spellcheck, so it's fine.

Mixed sentences are something else. For some real case example taken from a document I'm working on:

> "Vous pouvez utiliser CASE dans les instructions telles que SELECT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE et SET, ainsi que dans les clauses telles que
>   select_list, IN, WHERE, ORDER BY et HAVING"

Word is set to recognize automatically the language I'm using and  will correctly interpret the sentence as being in French, but I have to manually tell it to ignore all the sql intructions, one by one. Sometimes it might be a marketing or legal document.

I'm trying to avoid doing it bit by bit. Ideally, it would work for grammar as well.

Answer (score 1):

Write the citations of a specific langage using a specific (custom?) style in Word.

Then, when you have many (or all) entries, right click on one of them, choose the pop-up menu entry allowing you to select all words "having the same style", and then choose/force (for all these selected bits of text at once) the appropriate langage.

(I can't give specific menu entries, i use an older Word version at work).

To do the first part easily :

If you copy the procedures from some terminal (ex: Putty) you can set it to use a specific font and to enable RTF copy (this works in Putty. Use a similar trick, if you are not copying from Putty... for example use a specific editor for the procedures. Or first paste them in a separate document, and force on all a specific font/style)

Then you paste into Word with this specific font. (That's why you need to enable rtf copy in Putty)

That way, it's easy to then select all the same text with that specific font/style and set its langage, like explained above.

Or, if you can't do this (ex, existing documents with already mixed langages) :

ctrl + select all the same langage parts.

It's a bit tedious (proceed maybe paragraph per paragraph, if you don't want to redo it all) but it can be very fast.

Once all (or all a paragraph worth) of the same langage is selected, use the appropriate menu entry to set this selections' langage.

Comment: @ olivier dulac and @hannu edited my question in answer to your comments. I know how to it manually in several ways, I'd like a more permanent solutions, if someone has one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mark separate portions as being a certain language. Similar to selecting typefaces/size.